# How do I put a presenter widget behind a split point?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

How do I put a presenter widget behind a split point with gWTP?

Putting top level presenters behind splitpoints is straightforward as GWTP supports this out of the box but I'm not sure how to do it widget presenters... i.e. ones that are injected and don't have a proxy/place.

I'm using GWTP 1.0.

I've read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/gwt-platform/widgetfactory/gwt-platform/b2DCajL-riw) - it's all I could find on the subject - not so obvious and I think a little out of date (not for GWTP 1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/issues/333. You need to manually setup an AsyncProvider with Gin.

As well as [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gwt-platform/CodeSplitting%2420with%2420PresenterWidget%2420/gwt-platform/1h-TemavIcg/WzlnPfNDnaYJ) should help.